# JAX-RS Request Body Validation

Tags: rest, http-post, jax-rs

We are using JAX-RS to implement a REST API for one of our projects. Requirement is that the users would pass in the request object in JSON format.

Let us assume that we have a method that is invoked on hitting an API endpoint

```
@POST
@PATH("/api/user")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public CustomResponse methodA(@RequestBody UserInfo userDTO)
```

Sample Request Object:

{
       "firstName":"Test",
       "lastName":"Name",
       "sno":"A123"
   }

```
UserInfo DTO
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String sno;
```

getters and setters

Now if the user tries to add other parameters to the request object given above (for ex: "age") and invokes api endpoint, we have not been able to intercept and report the same back to the user saying "Invalid parameter age" as it seems that the request is being filtered out for invalid/unknown parameters and not reporting any error as such.

Any thoughts on how this can be addressed?

Comment: Which implementation of JAX-RS do you use? Jersey? Which serializer do you use (Jackson?).

Comment: Yes, Jersey and Jackson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify unrecognized properties by adding following piece of code:

Change the method signature to 
    public CustomResponse methodA(@RequestBody String reqObj)

and then

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
UserInfo userDTO = mapper.readValue(reqObj, UserInfo.class);
```

We now see a 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "<>" for any unsupported parameter

Comment: You could also put `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false)` on your `UserInfo` class.